# Can i have HashSets as the keys in a HashMap? Suggest an alternative if not

Tags: java, hashmap, set, hashset

Edit: explained the problem properly now.

I have a hashmap where i want to store sets of words seen together (key) and the lines in which they were seen together(value). This is the structure i came up with:

```
HashMap<HashSet<String>, HashSet<Integer>> hm= ...
```

for inputs:

1. mango, banana, apple
2. apple, banana
3. peach, walrus
4. walrus, peach

As I read this, line by line, I make new temporary keys (hashsets not yet inserted into hashmap) from the combination of words in the line. Each temporary key is a hashset of a subset of the words in the line. If a temporary key already exists in my hashmap, which i check by

```
if(hashmap.containsKey(hashset))
```

i simply add the new line to that key's corresponding value, if not, I make a new entry in the hashmap and take care of it.

At no point do i change an existing key. I only update their corresponding values in the hasmmap.

my hashmap, at the end of reading the file, should look something like this

[apple, banana]=[1,2]

[peach, walrus]=[3,4]

...

the problem is that the

```
if(hashmap.containsKey(hashset))
```

piece of code doesn't always detect existing keys. Why is this? Is this structure not allowed?

Thank you

Comment: Wouldn't line 5 be mapped to `peach, walrus` as well? And what about `mango` ?

Comment: @pcalcao yes. it behaves strangely. sometimes it detects the set to exist, sometimes not. I just want validation of whether HashMap can handle hashset has a key.

Comment: @Thomas. sorry, typo. removed it.

Comment: You can make it work for you..

Comment: If you doing a one-on-one mapping to key and value then definitely its a bad idea. As the ordering is not guaranteed in the set. For Ex if you are planning to map apple to 1 and banana to 2 this data structure is not going to work.

Answer (score 8):

This should work, but you need to watch out for mutability of the keys.  If you ever change the contents of one of the keys, its hashcode will change, and your map will start doing strange things.  From the javadoc for [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html):

> Note: great care must be exercised if mutable objects are used as map
>   keys. The behavior of a map is not specified if the value of an object
>   is changed in a manner that affects equals comparisons while the
>   object is a key in the map. A special case of this prohibition is that
>   it is not permissible for a map to contain itself as a key. While it
>   is permissible for a map to contain itself as a value, extreme caution
>   is advised: the equals and hashCode methods are no longer well defined
>   on such a map.

To avoid this, wrap the keys with `Collections.unmodifiableSet()` immediately upon creation, or just use [`ImmutableSet`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableSet.html) from Guava.

Comment: @matt hi, i've rephrased the question now. It wasn't very clearly explained. At no point do i change the keys, i only update the values to which the point to in the hashmap.

Answer (score 4):

You can, but once you have added a `HashSet` as a key to a `HashMap` you shouldn't modify it again, as the `HashSet.hashCode()` might change and you'll never find your `HashSet` again. In other words, if you're doing something like that, be sure that your keys are immutable `HashSets` (see also [Matt's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9773985/521799))

An alternative is to use the [`MultiKeyMap`](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/map/MultiKeyMap.html) along with a [`MultiKey`](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections/keyvalue/MultiKey.html) from [commons collections](http://commons.apache.org/collections/)

Comment: +1 by me but why should he use an alternative?He could just overide the `equals` and `hashcode` in `hashset`

Comment: @user384706: The OP asked for a possible alternative

Comment: Ok but he could just extend `hashset`.I can't think of a reason why it wouldn't suffice

Comment: @user384706: There's no need to extend `HashSet`... But why don't you post an answer illustrating what you mean?

Comment: Ok, I posted something.Perhaps I am not seeing something correctly

Comment: @LukasEder i won't be changing the key, just the values. in the code i wrote, if(hashmap.containskey(hashset))... doesn't always tell me if the set already exists. still looking for errors...

Comment: @Arjun: The reason for this is that you must not change the `HashSet` again, after you have added it as a key to the `HashMap`. As I said, if you do change it, you will probably not find it again as a key...

Comment: @LukasEder wait... you mean i can't change the value corresponding to the key in the map after the 1st time i've entered it? Just to be clear, i don't change the contents of the key, just the value that it points to. new line numbers are added to the value hashset, not key.

Comment: @Arjun: This question is becoming quite confusing... I'm not sure what you're doing and where the problem is

Comment: @LukasEder sorry about that. I've re written the question now. thanks though.

Comment: @Arjun: Great, that's better! :-)

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is well explained by @Lukas ans @Matt.
I think you could get away by using extending or using a decorator pattern to create a `Hashset` that overides `equals` and `hashCode` in a way that is independent of the contents.

This way you can avoid introducing dependencies on third party jars just for a specific problem

Comment: That's an interesting option! It's hard to tell from the OP's text, whether it will produce the wanted results, though...

Comment: I was just wondering if there is some pitfall I am not seeing.IMHO it is good to avoid introducing extra libraries if you don't really use them